# How to sort data according to date using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

l have data JSON coming from URL and l displayed those data in a table.

[image]

As you see l have different time dates. l want to add a new element above '12:15 am' to display the full date to make the user know that is a new day as the image below.

[image]

Code :

```
    function airport() {
    
            var airport_data = ""
    
            $.ajax('my_airport.json', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    cache: false,
    
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    
                    data.forEach(element => {
                           
                            if (element.flight.status.generic.status.text == 'scheduled') {
                                    airport_data += '<tr>';
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.airline.name + '</p></td>';
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.identification.number.default + '</p></td>';
                                    if (element.flight.aircraft == null) {
                                            airport_data += '<td><p>N/A</p></td>';
                                    } else {
                                            airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.aircraft.model.code + '</p></td>';
                                    }
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city + '</p></td>';
/// time is here
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + moment.unix(element.flight.time.scheduled.arrival).format("h:mm a") + '</p></td>';
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.status.generic.status.text + '</p></td>';
                                    if (!element.flight.time.scheduled.arrival) airport_data += "<tr><td><p>N/A</p></td></tr>";
    
                            } 
                            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = airport_data
                            var rows = $("#data");
                            rows.hide();
                            $('.row-data:last-child').after(rows);
                            rows.fadeIn(500);
                    });
    
            })
    
    
    
    }
```

html :

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed text-center table-hover"">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>AIRLINES</th>
                <th>CALLSIGN</th>
                <th>TYPE</th>
                <th>FROM</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data" class="data">

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows comes already sorted you just have to insert the additional rows every time the date is going to change. Do it this way:

- before entering the forEach initialize a variable called prevDate with an empty string;
- inside the foreach, before appending the flight row, format the arrival as YYYYMMDD and assign it to a variable called currentDate;
- compare currentDate with prevDate, if they differ then add the date header;
- assign currentDate to prevDate.

That's all.

**EDIT**

First, let me say you have a syntax error in your html, you have closed the double quote 2 times on the table class.

Second, your js code is iterating over the root of the json returned by the ajax call, but the json you have added in the comment has a more nested structure, the array is located down to "data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data".

So, after resambling the above, your code should become like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.x-git.min.js"></script>
        <script src="moment.js"></script>
        <script>
$(airport);

function airport() {
    
            var airport_data = ""
    
            $.ajax('my_airport.json', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    cache: false,
    
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var prevDate = '';
                    data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data.forEach(element => {
                            var curDate = moment.unix(element.flight.time.scheduled.arrival).format("YYYYMMDD");
                            if (curDate != prevDate) {
                                airport_data += '<tr><td colspan="5">ARRIVALS - '+
                                    moment.unix(element.flight.time.scheduled.arrival).format("dddd, MMM D")+
                                    '</td></tr>';
                                prevDate = curDate;
                            }
                            if (element.flight.status.generic.status.text == 'scheduled') {
                                    airport_data += '<tr>';
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.airline.name + '</p></td>';
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.identification.number.default + '</p></td>';
                                    if (element.flight.aircraft == null) {
                                            airport_data += '<td><p>N/A</p></td>';
                                    } else {
                                            airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.aircraft.model.code + '</p></td>';
                                    }
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city + '</p></td>';
/// time is here
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + moment.unix(element.flight.time.scheduled.arrival).format("h:mm a") + '</p></td>';
                                    airport_data += '<td><p>' + element.flight.status.generic.status.text + '</p></td>';
                                    if (!element.flight.time.scheduled.arrival) airport_data += "<tr><td><p>N/A</p></td></tr>";
    
                            } 
                            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = airport_data
                            var rows = $("#data");
                            rows.hide();
                            $('.row-data:last-child').after(rows);
                            rows.fadeIn(500);
                    });
    
            })
}
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed text-center table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>AIRLINES</th>
                        <th>CALLSIGN</th>
                        <th>TYPE</th>
                        <th>FROM</th>
                        <th>TIME</th>
                        <th>STATUS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="data" class="data">
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rest is a matter of styling.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Can you please give me an example code?  l am beginner with this :/

Comment: But how l can make the date YYYYMMDD in the first index of the new date? such as the second image?

Comment: check out my json https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.65f2f442d2f945599a97428f321a8b3e

Comment: @AliGhassan I have edited the answer with the code changed and fixed.

Comment: unbelievable. its works. Thank you so much.